# Unable to download internet hosted text file from within Android app

Tags: android, url, android-asynctask, network-protocols, filenotfoundexception

I am developing an Android application in which I need to download a text file hosted at :-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2smsdqknrjg5zda/try1.txt/?dl=0

from within my app and get/load its content in a text-view.
I am doing the download using **AsyncTask's doInBackground()** method.

Here is the code in the MainActivity.java that I have come up with so far.
The file is getting downloaded in **/storage/sdcard/file_try7.ext** but for some reason, its size is 0 which I saw in the DDMS.

In the LogCat section, I am getting the message "**java.io.FileNotFoundException**".

Can someone please take a look and see what the issue might be..??

package com.example.xxxxx;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.InputFilter.LengthFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        //execute on background (out of the UI thread)




    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
            //this is the file to be downloaded


            URL url = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/2smsdqknrjg5zda/try1.txt/?dl=0");

            //create the new connection
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //set up some things on the connection
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            //and connect!
            urlConnection.connect();

            //set the path where we want to save the file
            //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
            //sd card.
            File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
            //which we want to save the file as.
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"menu7.ext");
    //        if (!file.exists()) {
      //          file.createNewFile();
        //    }

            //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            //variable to store total downloaded bytes
            int downloadedSize = 0;

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                    //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                    //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
                    //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

            }
            //close the output stream when done
            fileOutput.close();

    //catch some possible errors...
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
    public void get_menu(View v)
    {
        MyAsyncTask async = new MyAsyncTask();
        async.execute();
        //Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(),"Inside get_menu",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    //Method to get the FileInputStream object as a string.
            public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                reader.close();
                return sb.toString();
            }

            /*Method to get text of the file with path as filePath as string by calling 
              convertStreamToString.*/
            public static String getStringFromFile (String filePath) throws Exception {
                File fl = new File(filePath);
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
                String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
                fin.close();        
                return ret;
          }



    public void load_menu(View v)
    {
        //Method which actually loads the text by calling the getStringFromFile method.
            String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            EditText editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            //String fileName=editText2.getText().toString();
            String path  = baseDir + "/" + "menu7" + ".ext";

            try {
                    String inp_string=getStringFromFile(path);
                //EditText editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                editText2.setText(inp_string);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(),"File not found.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }





    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the url via get method and that's why it is not giving you output file in buffer but the link to download the file. check the screenshot below.Make sure you download the file and then get the file into buffer. But I wonder why do you need to do that if you've already downloaded the file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6AnN.png

Comment: Could you please tell me how to download the file rather than the link..??
Also, the file has not already been downloaded, it is downloaded from within the app whenever user clicks a button.

Comment: you need to use download manager class look for android documentation. It's a simple process. It is well explained in their website. If you want any help after post here.